# Is it possible to print out an int as binary using only division, rest and recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

So long story short, for an introductory Java class I was tasked to create a recursive function that looks like

```
printDual(int n)
```

To print n in binary. Along with this I'm also only allowed to use division and rest operators. My first thought was to use

```
  printDual(int n) {
    if(n > 0) {
      System.out.print(n%2);
      printDual(n/2);
    }
  }
```

but this just prints it backwards. Can anyone think of a way to solve this within the restrictions?

Comment: First thought: try to swap the `println` and the `printDual` calls.

Comment: swap the statements!? ;) (1. recurse 2. system.out)

Comment: The thought that I would have would be subtracting 2 ^ (maximum number possible) from n and then decrease n by 1, into a loop. While this happens, use some kind of storage method to find the binary string based on this information.

Comment: Oh right. Then use a method that does that, using multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just think reverse one time and recursive solution will become obvious
try this :

```
    void printDual(int n) {
    if (n>0) {
        printDual(n/2);
        System.out.print(n%2);
    }
```